# Cannot see changes in database without running manually the commit command

Tags: c#, firebird

I'm trying to save the data I'm inserting into a local Firebird database.

I've tried running an sql command, in the C# code, containg `commit;` after inserting the data but it doesn't seem to work. The informations are sent but the database isn't saving them.

This is the code I'm using for inserting the data.

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new FbConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = "localhost",
                Port = 3050,
                Database = @"D:\db\DBUTENTI.FDB",
                UserID = "SYSDBA",
                Password = "masterkey",
                ServerType = FbServerType.Default
            };

            using (FbConnection myConn = new FbConnection(csb.ToString()))
            {
                if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        myConn.Open();
                        Console.WriteLine("CONNECTION OPENED");
                        string Id = txt_Id.Text;
                        string Utente = txt_User.Text;
                        string Password = txt_Password.Text;
                        FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("insert into utenti(id,utente,password)values(@id, @utente, @password)", myConn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", Id);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("utente", Utente);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", Password);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        myConn.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine("CONNECTION CLOSED");
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The code runs without any errors/exceptions, but I have to manually commit in the ISQL Tool to see the changes.

Thanks to anyone who is willing to help.

Comment: Note that the `FbCommand commit ...` part of your code is not necessary. If you execute without beginning a transaction in C#, it is automatically committed. And if you do begin a transaction, then you should commit using the `FbTransaction` object, not by executing a commit statement.

Comment: Yep, I was just trying random solutions. Thank you, I will remove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your workaround (solution) is to manually commit in ISQL, the problem is that you had an active transaction in ISQL (and one is started as soon as you start ISQL). This transaction cannot see changes from transactions committed after the transaction in ISQL started (ie: the changes in your program).

ISQL by default starts transactions with the SNAPSHOT isolation level (which is somewhat equivalent to the SQL standard REPEATABLE READ). If you want ISQL to be able to see changes made by your program, you either need to relax its isolation level to READ COMMITTED, or - as you already found out - you need to explicitly commit (so a new transaction is used).

For example to switch ISQL to use READ COMMITTED, you can use statement:

```sql
set transaction read committed record_version;
```

This will only change the transaction setting for the current session.

For details, see

- [Firebird 2.5 Language Reference, Transaction Statements](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-transacs-statements)
- [ISQL, Transaction Handling](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-transactions)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I'll try to relax the isolation level.
Also thanks for the statament you posted.

Comment: Just to add a little info, you have to run the statement above every time you open the ISQL Tool.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, ISQL will always default to SNAPSHOT; I have made an explicit comment that it only applies to the current session.

Comment: Is there a setting that can enable it by default? Just for curiosity.

Comment: @Adrian No, there is no setting in ISQL for this.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers :)